# Load error when trying to include custom module

Tags: ruby, sinatra, basic-authentication

Same app, different problem. I'm working on an app using the Dan Benjamin "Meet Sinatra" screencast as a reference. I'm trying to include a custom authentication module, which is housed in a lib folder (lib/authentication.rb). I am requiring that line at the top of my code, but when I try to load the page, it claims there is no such file to load.

Any thoughts?

Here's the top of my main Sinatra file:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'rubygems'
require 'datamapper'
require 'dm-core'
require 'lib/authorization'

DataMapper::setup(:default, "sqlite3://#{Dir.pwd}/entries.db")

class Entry
include DataMapper::Resource

property :id,           Serial
property :first_name,   String
property :last_name,    String
property :email,        String
property :created_at,   DateTime    

end

# create, upgrade, or migrate tables automatically
DataMapper.auto_upgrade!

helpers do
include Sinatra::Authorization
end
```

And the actual Module:

```
module Sinatra
  module Authorization

  def auth
    @auth ||= Rack::Auth::Basic::Request.new(request.env)
  end

  def unauthorized!(realm="Short URL Generator")
    headers 'WWW-Authenticate' => %(Basic realm="#{realm}")
    throw :halt, [ 401, 'Authorization Required' ]
  end

  def bad_request!
    throw :halt, [ 400, 'Bad Request' ]
  end

  def authorized?
    request.env['REMOTE_USER']
  end

  def authorize(username, password)
    if (username=='topfunky' && password=='peepcode') then
      true
  else
    false
  end
end

def require_admin
  return if authorized?
  unauthorized! unless auth.provided?
  bad_request! unless auth.basic?
  unauthorized! unless authorize(*auth.credentials)
  request.env['REMOTE_USER'] = auth.username
end

  def admin?
    authorized?
  end

  end
end
```

Then, on any of the handlers I want to protect, I put "require_admin."

Comment: Can you post the exact code you're using to try and load that file?

Comment: Added a blank line between the end of your text and the start of your code, so that all your code is formatted as code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming you're using Ruby 1.9, the default `$LOAD_PATH` no longer includes the current directory. So while statements like `require 'sinatra'` work just fine (because those gems are in `$LOAD_PATH`), Ruby doesn't know that your `lib/authorization` file is located relative to your main Sinatra file.

You can add the Sinatra file's directory to the load path, and then your `require` statements should work fine:

```
$LOAD_PATH.unshift(File.dirname(__FILE__))
require 'sinatra'
require 'rubygems' # Not actually needed on Ruby 1.9
require 'datamapper'
require 'dm-core'
require 'lib/authorization'
```

Comment: That did it. I guess the tutorial I'm following was done in ruby 1.8. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 7):

Personnaly, I use a "relative" path since I work with Ruby 1.9.2 :

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'rubygems' # Not actually needed on Ruby 1.9
require 'datamapper'
require 'dm-core'
require './lib/authorization'
```

But I never check what would happen if my code should work on Ruby 1.8.6 again.

Comment: In my opinion, this one should be the accepted answer. So far I've been using the hack with unshifting the load path, but it was always so ugly to me, and this is the solution I've been searching for :)

Comment: I like this option as it invites less code. **But both options work!**